# How to modify a pointer through a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-search-tree

So I want to pass a pointer to a function and have that function modify that pointer from inside that function. **How do i do that in general? In here?**

**EDIT:**

Since the treeNode is a struct of pointers I want to take `nodePtr->vendorDataRef` inside of the `removeLeftMostNode(...)` function and somehow get it back to the calling function. I thought I could do this through a parameter of `removeLeftMostNode(...)` hence `removeLeftMostNode(...aVendor* vendorDataRef)`

i.e.

```
aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeNode(aBst::treeNode * nodePtr)
{
    aVendor * tempVendorPtr; //<----...to be assigned to this
    treeNode * nodeToConnectPtr, * tempPtr;
    ...
    tempPtr = removeLeftMostNode(nodePtr->right, &tempVendorPtr);
    ...
 }

aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeLeftMostNode(aBst::treeNode * nodePtr, aVendor* vendorDataRef)
{
    if(nodePtr->left == NULL)
    {
        //Target acquired, modify the value of vendorData through parameter
        vendorDataRef = nodePtr->vendorData; //<---I want this pointer... 
        return removeNode(nodePtr);
    }
    else
        return removeLeftMostNode(nodePtr->left, vendorData);
    }
```

This is the treeNode struct

```
struct treeNode
{
    aVendor * vendorData;
    treeNode * left;
    treeNode * right;
};
```

As you might guess, this is a part of the code to remove an entry from a binary search tree. This is the code that calls it indirectly.

```
bool aBst::remove(char nameOfVendor[])
{
    bool failControl = false;

    removeValue(root, nameOfVendor, failControl);

    return failControl;
}

aBst::treeNode * aBst::removeValue(aBst::treeNode * subTreePtr, char nameOfVendor[], bool& success)
{
    //Note: the subTreePtr should be root in initial call
    treeNode * tmpPtr;
    char name[MAX_CHAR_LENGTH];

    subTreePtr->vendorData->getName(name);

    if(subTreePtr == NULL) //Empty Tree
    {
        success = false;
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(strcmp(name, nameOfVendor) == 0) //Evaluates to true if there is a match
        {
            //Item is in root of subTreePtr
            subTreePtr = removeNode(subTreePtr);
            success = true;
            return subTreePtr;
        }
        else if(strcmp(name, nameOfVendor) < 0) // Go left
            {
                tmpPtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->left, nameOfVendor, success);
                subTreePtr->left = tmpPtr;
                return subTreePtr;
            }
            else // Go Right
            {
                tmpPtr = removeValue(subTreePtr->right, nameOfVendor, success);
                subTreePtr->right = tmpPtr;
                return subTreePtr;
            }
}
```

Comment: "I want to avoid passing by value," Almost every parameter (except `success`) is passed by value. "if i use a pointer to a pointer I'm afraid that it won't modify the value of `tempVendorPtr` in `removeNode`" Why are you afraid, it *will* modify the pointer. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem exactly? Or what and where are you trying to achieve the "_pass a pointer to a function and have that function modify that pointer_"

Comment: Receive it by reference. Rather trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i do that in general?

To modify any object, be it an object or pointer to object, you can pass a reference to it.

```
void foo(int& i)
{
   // Assign to i. The change will be visible in the calling function.
   i = 10;
}

void bar(int*& ptr)
{
   // Assign to ptr dynamically allocated memory.
   // The memory will be valid in the calling function.
   ptr = new int[20];
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   int* ptr;

   foo(i); // When the function returns, i will be 10
   bar(ptr);  // When the function returns ptr will point to an array of 10 ints
   ptr[5] = 20;  // OK since memory for ptr was allocated in bar.

   ...

   // Deallocate memory to prevent memory leak.
   delete [] ptr;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that second example was exactly what I was looking for. I tried something like that but my error was calling bar like bar(&ptr)